# Azure Container Registry Webhook to App Service 401

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-container-registry

I have an Azure App Service that pulls a container image from an Azure Container Registry (ACR) when the App Service starts. I'm trying to have an ACR Webhook notify the App Service that a new container is available and to restart automatically. However, while the Webhook runs fine from an ADO pipeline, I get a "401 Unauthorized" error.

From the App Service, I've turned on "Continuous Deployment" and copied the Webhook URL to the Service URI in the ACR Webhook:

[image: App Service Config]

The App Service has "AcrPull" permissions on the Container Registry:

[image: ACR Permissions]

Even running a Ping on the Webhook results in a 401 with this configuration:

[image: Ping 401]

What am I missing? I don't see anything in particular that I've skipped in the Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> Azure Container Registry Webhook to App Service 401:

*Need to check below:*

Verify the permissions for which you are added (User or a service principal), even if you provided the appropriate permissions for fetching the registry through App service.

Because to be able to pull from ACR, you must assign the `AcrPull` role to a "Managed Identity or Service Principal".

Sometimes the ACR webhook does not have authorization to access App service.  To resolve this, add the ACR Webhook IP address to the App Service's IP Restrictions.

In few scenarios, App Service may not set up to use the proper authentication method. Check the authentication in the App Service's `Authentication` in settings.

[image]

If still the issue persists, try to authenticate with the admin credentials as shown.

[image]

Check whether any firewall or Ip restrictions are existed for the App service as well as container registries.

If none of the above helps, check the logs by visiting into logs of the deployment center under deployment option in an app service.

[image]

I tried the same in my environment with the below added permissions and a registered app in Azure AD and it worked as follows.

[image]

[image]

Other solutions like ACR Tasks feature or developing a custom solution with Azure Event Grid and Azure Functions, may be required if it is not resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the a) setting up an authentication provider as you have didn't help, b) AcrPull is already added to the ACR for the App Service, c) using Admin Creds didn't help, d) how do I get the IP address of the Webhook?

Comment: Additionally, the ping is successful as you've shown above, but inspecting the ping shows it resulted in a 401 - unauthorized. So while the Webhook executes fine and responds to a new ACR image, the Webhook isn't able to access the App Service for some reason to notify it to pull.

Comment: @gt-downunder were you able to figure this out? I am facing same issue now as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796672/azure-container-registry-acr-webhook-to-app-service-with-container-apps-fail

Answer (score 2):

Posted this answer to a similar question, posting it here as well for visibility.

Make sure the "Basic Auth Publishing Credentials" is enabled for the App Service. Since the webhook uses basic auth for authentication, this needs to be enabled for it to work. Once we enabled this setting, the webhook started to work as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `az resource update --resource-group <resource-group> --name scm --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies --parent sites/<site-name> --set properties.allow=true`